# How to differentiate fuzzy matching from artificial intelligence

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, deep-neural-networks, logic, fuzzy-logic

I am curious about the term "fuzzy matching," and whether it falls under the category of artificial intelligence. Specifically, when can we say that a website or system is using AI, and when do we simply attribute it to clever algorithms or rule-based programming?